# How to dynamically set a random Material on a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a total newcomer to unity and I was just wondering how to set a material from C#?

I have a prefab model and I can change the texture from the editor no problem.  What I want to do is randomly set the material when an instance of the prefab is generated.

Here is the field I want to change:

[image: Unity Field]

And I am creating these with the following code:

```
Instantiate(eggPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
```

(Where eggPrefab is a public Transform).

I hope that is enough information!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mixing the random material behaviour with creation behaviour is overcomplicating things. Just create a component that randomises a GameObject's material on [Start](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) and it will run when you instantiate your prefab.

```
public class MaterialRandomiser : MonoBehaviour {

  [SerializeField]
  private Material[] _materials;
  [SerializeField]
  private Renderer _renderer;

  public void Start () {
    ChangeMaterial();
  }

  public void Reset () {
    _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
  }

  public void ChangeMaterial () {
    _renderer.material = SelectRandomMaterial();
  }

  private Material SelectRandomMaterial () {
    return _materials[Random.Range(0, _materials.Length)];
  }

}
```

Attach it to your prefab and now when you spawn them, they will have random materials. You now also have the option to use the same code on non-prefab objects as well. Just don't forget to assign the materials!

Comment: This was actually super easy to add without changing any of my existing code.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

After you instantiate the GameObject, get the MeshRenderer from it then change it's material:

```
public GameObject eggPrefab;
public Vector3 spawnPos;
public Material mat;

void Start()
{
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(eggPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
    obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = mat;
}
```

If you don't have the material then you can create one with a shader and assign it to the MeshRenderer:

```
GameObject obj = Instantiate(eggPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);

//Find the Standard Shader
Material mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
//Set Texture on the material
//mat.SetTexture("_MainTex", yourTexture);

obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = mat;
```

---

Finally, if you have more than one material then use the `materials` property instead of the `material` property and assign your array of material to it:

```
GameObject obj = Instantiate(eggPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);

//Find the Standard Shader
Material mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
//Set Texture on the material
//mat.SetTexture("_MainTex", yourTexture);

//Create array of mats (Create one for example)
Material[] mats = new Material[1];
mats[0] = mat;

obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials = mats;
```

**Edit:**

I missed the random part. If you want random material selection, just use `Random.Range` to select one item from the array of Material.

```
public GameObject eggPrefab;
public Vector3 spawnPos;
public Material[] mats;

void Start()
{
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(eggPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
    int matIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, mats.Length);
    obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = mats[matIndex];
}
```

Comment: @ls_dev Every time you assign to Renderer.material you're (somehow) assigning a new instance of your material and increasing your number of draw calls. Always use Renderer.sharedMaterial to avoid this.

Comment: @KevinRemo No. Not every time. It happens **once** only for each call on the renderer. Aslo, there are times when you need `Renderer.material` then `Renderer.sharedMaterial`. It totally depends on what OP is doing because if you have many objects/prefabs referencing one material,  `Renderer.material`  should be used to change their **individual** colors. If you want to change all the color of objects using that material, use `Renderer.sharedMaterial`. OP may use MaterialBlock to prevent creating new instances but it breaks batching.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will try this tomorrow and update the thread.

Comment: @ls_dev It should be noted that `Renderer.material` *automatically* clones materials when its first invoked. Its one of those "does things to be easy on the developer" helper functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following using an materials array.

```
    public Material[] materialsArray;
    public GameObject prefab;
    private Vector3 pos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    private Quaternion rot = Quaternion.identity;

    private void Start()
    {
        Material mat = RandomMaterial(materialsArray);
        InstantiateWithMaterial(prefab, pos, rot, mat);
    }

    public Material RandomMaterial(Material[] _array_)
    {
        return _array_[Random.Range(0, _array_.Length)];
    }

    public void InstantiateWithMaterial(GameObject _prefab_, Vector3 _pos_, Quaternion _rot_, Material _mat_)
    {
        GameObject obj_ = Instantiate(_prefab_, _pos_, _rot_);
        obj_.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = _mat_;
    }
```

This should work how you want, just place on an empty GameObject and populate the materials array with all the materials you want.